# How to return first not empty cell from importrange values?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

my google sheet excel document contain data like this

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C | D | E | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   | c |   | x |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 |   | r |   | 4 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 |   |   |   | m |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Column **B** and **D** contain data provided by `IMPORTRANGE` function, which are store in different files.

And i would like to fill column **A** with first not empty value in row, in other words: desired result must look like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C | D | E | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | c | c |   | x |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | r | r |   | 4 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | m |   |   | m |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I tried `ISBLANK` function, but apperantly if column is imported then, even if the value is empty, is not blank, so this function dosn't work for my case. Then i tried `QUERY` function in 2 different variant:

1) `=QUERY({B1;D1}; "select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1"; 0)` but result in this case is wrong when row contain cells with numbers. Result with this query is following:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C | D | E | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | c | c |   | x |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 4 | r |   | 4 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | m |   |   | m |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

2) `=QUERY({B1;D1};"select Col1 where Col1 <> '' limit 1"; 0)` / `=QUERY({B1;D1};"select Col1 where Col1 != '' limit 1"; 0)` and this dosn't work at all, result is always `#N/A`

Also i would like to avoid using nested `IFs` and javascript scripts, if possible, as solution with `QUERY` function suits for my case best due to easy expansion to another columns without any deeper knowladge about programming. Is there any way how to make it simply, just with `QUERY`, and i am just missing something, or i have to use IFs/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(B:G, " ", "♦")),,99^99))), " ")),,1), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]

---

**selective columns:**

[image: 0]

Comment: This dosn't work too, because i have to select exact columns, from example above it would be like `{B1:B;D1:D}`, in this case **B** and **D** refer to last cell in column, beacues of this i have to multiple numbers of rows in whole document by numbers of selected columns (#REF!: Error Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows (50500) ). I guess this is because when range is wrapped in { } brackets, then is outside of document context, empty cells included.

Comment: `{B1:B\D1:D}` this is give me parse error, so i guess this is most likely from excel, as excel change syntax on windows regional settings and if comma is deciaml symbol, then \ is used in place of comma in Array. If semi colon is decimal symbol, then \ is used in place of semi colon in Array. Never saw this separator for array in google sheets.